# Radiobutton "Checked" method doesn't work

Tags: c#, radio-button, win-universal-app, checked

I have an unknown problem with building my first UWP App.

On button onclick method I want to check if one of checkboxes is checked and if yes I want to open a new frame:

```
namespace IDG
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void bt_start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (rb_quiz.Checked)
            {
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Visual Studio marks error on that line:
`if (rb_quiz.Checked)`

The popup says:

> The Event '`ToggleButton.Checked`' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -"

I have checked "`==Checked`" or "`isChecked`". But nothing works. My `radiobutton` is called `rb_quiz`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227544), `Checked` is an event that "Fires when a ToggleButton is checked". You instead want to use the property `IsChecked`

Answer (score 1):

`Checked` is an Event, you are looking for `IsChecked` which is a `Nullable<Boolean>`.

Try this:

```
if (rb_quiz.IsChecked == true)
```